# Firebase Real-time Database name and value

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I am an amateur app developer. I am now trying to build a messaging app for iOS. But I have some hard times understanding the realtime firebase database. I don't understand the value and the name section when you press the plus sign.

[image: The things I can't understand]

Answer (score 3):

The value and name section you mention is a tool for designing the structure of your database. Firebase uses a very popular style of NoSQL database: Key-value stores. The concept is not so complicated once you know the basic JSON syntax.

Here's an example from an iOS app I built. The whole diagram is a JSON object. The keys have to be strings, just like the "orders" key below.  The value must be a valid JSON data type (string, number, object, array, boolean or null), which is an object in this case. And it goes on like that...

[image]

Try [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2).

Cheers, Tim!